# Live Preview not working - showing home page instead

Tags: live-preview

I've got a Structure entry, enabled, but Live Preview (or just viewing the page on the public site) shows the home page instead.

Might I have a setting incorrect?

**Edit**: It looks like previewing any entry shows me the home page.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I forgot to call the block in the _layout template!